# How to call functions on Maximize(not resize) of a scene in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, maximize-window

I can add a ChangeListener to a Scene and call it on the scene.widthProperty() and 
scene.heightProperty(), but this doesn't apply when the window is maximized via the Maximize button.

I can't find any onResize property of the window when it is accessed like scene.getWindow()

Here's what I have to resize columns in a table based off resizing the window.

How can I make that resizeColumns listener be added to when the whole window is Maximized (which doesn't qualify as a scene.widthProperty() or scene.heightProperty()

```
        ChangeListener<Object> resizeColumns = new ChangeListener<Object>(){

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2) {
                new Thread() {
                    // runnable for that thread

                    public void run() {
                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
                            public void run() {
                                // what will be ran in gui thread


                                Double width =primaryStage.getWidth();
                                DraftController controller = (DraftController)loader.getController();
                                TableView<Player> teamTable =controller.getTeamTable();
                                centerColumns(width, controller, teamTable);


                                TableView<Player>  top10Table = controller.getTop10Table();

                                AnchorPane anchor = controller.getAnchorPane();
                                centerColumns(anchor.getWidth()+anchor.getWidth()*.04,controller,top10Table);
                            }


                            private void centerColumns(Double width, DraftController controller, TableView<Player> teamTable) {
                                ObservableList<TableColumn<Player, ?>> columnList = teamTable.getColumns();
                                for (int i=0 ; i<columnList.size(); i++){
                                    columnList.get(i).setPrefWidth((width-17)/teamTable.getColumns().size());
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }.start();

            }

        };

        scene.widthProperty().addListener(resizeColumns);
        scene.heightProperty().addListener(resizeColumns);
        guage: lang-java -->
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i can do this but it will be possible with class level declaration i.e static declaration..is it ok for you ??
then i give answer

Answer (score 1):

My little example works well on maximizing the stage:

```
package org.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ResizeScene extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final StackPane stack = new StackPane();
        final Text resolution = new Text();
        stack.getChildren().add(resolution);

        final Scene scene = new Scene(stack);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        final InvalidationListener resizeListener = new InvalidationListener() {
            @Override
            public void invalidated(final Observable observable) {
                final double width = scene.getWidth();
                final double height = scene.getHeight();
                resolution.setText(width + " x " + height);
            }
        };
        scene.widthProperty().addListener(resizeListener);
        scene.heightProperty().addListener(resizeListener);

        // Initial Size
        primaryStage.setWidth(800);
        primaryStage.setHeight(600);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't work for when you hit the maximize button. It works when you resize, but it doesn't work if the maximize button is clicked, and thats what I can't get

Comment: It works here on Windows 7, with the newest JDK 7u45. I press the maximize button and the listener's invalidate method get called.